# Not able to Login to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login

I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop. I was installing the updates and my laptop suddenly shutdown. After this when i start the laptop, only the initial login screen appears, when i type the username password it displays "Cannot login system problem detected" and returns to the login screen itself. Previously even if not logged icons (like wifi, shutdown icon) will be shown in top right corner now nothing is showing and also it displays network not connected, looks like wifi has been corrupted.

Is there any way we can login?? I tried with command prompt ALT + CTRL + F1. It is logging in. But i am not able to get the graphical display.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Can you log into the guest session???

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the permissions of your home folder since yuo are able to login using tty (ALT + CTRL + F1-6), usually this could appen when you lounch graphical application using sudo and then something goes wrong (like unexpected shutdown).

Before you run the following command, make [a full system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) as it can make things worse:

To restore the permissions of your home folder you can login using tty and type:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUPS $HOME
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  If you have to use "could", "might" , "try" it's a comment if you use "will" "shall" "do" it's an answer...